# How add new window on button click and come back to previous window?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uiapplicationdelegate, uiwindow

I have an application in which i have a button. I want to open a fb login url in browser and when i login successfully then i want to come back to my application. So problem is that how i fix that?

i use this code for.

```
-(IBAction)add_account:(id)sender{
    switch ( ((UIButton*)sender).tag ){
        case 0:
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&type=user_agent&display=touch&scope=offline_access,publish_stream,read_stream"]];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advances...

Answer (score 1):

You need to register an URL scheme for your own app. You can put the URL scheme in your app's project file on the "Info" tab, lower right is an "Add" button which allows to add an URL type. You can now edit that URL type in the list, especially filling out the identifier and more important the URL scheme. Assuming your URL scheme is "myapp":

Every URL starting with myapp:// now will be forwarded to your app. Now you simply have to implement `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation` in your application delegate which will handle all "myapp://" URLs. There you can, for example, extract information from the URL and show a specific view.

The myapp://-URL would of course go as redirect target in your original request.